# Python, Pandas, to_csv, os.path.join argument formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to putput a dataframe to csv, and have noticed that the following code works:

```
df.to_csv(os.path.join(string1, string2 + ".csv"))
```

However, on the other hand the following code does not work. Could someone kindly help me understand why?

```
df.to_csv(os.path.join(string1, string2, ".csv"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The two calls to `os.path.join` simply return different paths:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> string1, string2 = "X", "Y"
>>> os.path.join(string1, string2 + ".csv")
'X/Y.csv'
>>> os.path.join(string1, string2, ".csv")
'X/Y/.csv'
```

The latter will try to save a file called `'.csv'` in the subdirectory called `'Y'` of the directory `'X'`. The first code will try to save `'Y.csv'`, which is a different file, stored in the `'X'` directory.

The two lines give different file paths, so it makes sense that they can produce different behavior, since the in latter the `'Y'` directory apparently doesn't exist.

---

You can prevent future confusion by using the (somewhat, but not really) new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html) standard module:

```
from pathlib import Path

df.to_csv(Path(string1) / f"{string2}.csv")
```